# Adding __init__() method in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy in python 3.6.5 and -- so far -- have not been able to extend a model with a call to `__init__()`.  My code looks like this:

```
'''
file: models.py
'''
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Network(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'network'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    baud_rate = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(**kwargs):
        super(Network, self).__init__(**kwargs)  # see note
```

Attempting to instantiate a Network object results in an error:

```
>>> n = Network(baud_rate=300)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

This is a bit surprising, since I'm using [the recipe given in the Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/):

> If you decide to override the constructor for any reason, make sure to
>   keep accepting **kwargs and call the super constructor with those
>   **kwargs to preserve this behavior:
>   
>       `class Foo(db.Model):
>           # ...
>           def __init__(**kwargs):
>               super(Foo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
>               # do custom stuff`

Since I'm using python 3.6, I thought maybe I should upgrade the call to `super()`, as in :

```
def __init__(**kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

... but that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like the doc forgets to mention the `self` attribute in `__init__` (A [pull request](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/619) was accepted in may) :

```
class Network(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'network'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    baud_rate = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Yep - that did the trick.  Not quite what I expected, though!